# Would this mod-related question be viable on Arqade?

Tags: support

I have a problem with running [Morrowind Overhaul - Sounds And Graphics](http://www.nexusmods.com/morrowind/mods/36945/) on my fresh Morrowind installation (through Steam).

I deactivated Steam Overlay, even deactivated ingame MGE, but when I press on "New" to start a new game in the loading screen it crashes to desktop.

I also checked all options and I can't find issues. The problem itself is reproduceable as it happens everytime I try.

As I know that mod support is not welcome on Arqade but this mod seems to be a "must have", I would like to know if this question would be viable on Arqade.

Answer (score 1):

Is it on topic?

Sure, and I'm not sure how you got the impression that it wasn't.

Is it likely to get a good answer? Maybe, but probably not. Tech support isn't really something we do very well here; especially for oddball edge cases, rather than well known, commonly encountered, and specific, easily searchable error messages.

Is it likely to get downvoted? Also probably. There are some users who feel that because questions like this are often *unable to be answered* well here, that they represent poor contributions. Don't sweat it too much.

Comment: Your answer implies, that I should take the risk to question?

Comment: What risk? Remember, it only takes one up vote to offset the negative impact on your reputation from **five downvotes**.

Comment: Ok, then wish me good luck, Mr. Fizz. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz For questions, it takes **two** upvotes to offset the negative impact of five downvotes /pedant.

Comment: @fredley Right you are. I do always forget that. Point still stands.